# Scanner not found through SaneTwain/SaneWinDS/XSane

Tags: raspbian, cups

I've setup my Raspberry Pi B as print server and also wanted to use it for scanning over network.

OS: Raspbian Wheezy (debian-pi/raspbian-ua-netinst) uptodate

Printer/Scanner: HP Deskjet 2050 J510 AiO

I've installed cups and everything it was asking for. Cups picked up the printer and I can print without any issues. I installed sane and it also picked up the scanner of the Deskjet 2050 and I can scan throug the sane commandline tool "scanimage".

When I use SaneTwain/SaneWinDS or XSane for Windows no scanner devices are found through these Sane to Twain bridges although they can connect to the sane server hosted on my Raspberry Pi.

Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a bit late, but this could help some other persons...
I ran the same issue.
To solve it, I use the following links:

- https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2320859
- https://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?id=55302

The solution:

- Make sure the driver for your scanner is selected (files net.conf and usb.conf in /etc/sane.d directory ==> Message #9 of 2nd link)
- Make sure the "usb" directory in /dev/bus/usb is read/write for everybody (last message of 1st link).

Regards.